# How to Modify LED panel’s power board to turn it on/off using Arduino pro mini

Tags: arduino, power-supply, battery-operated

I’m a software developer and beginner in electronics.

My objective:

- I want to modify,
  [https://www.amazon.com/Ulanzi-Ultra-Bright-Video-Light/dp/B0757KCWGW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0757KCWGW)
  [image]

LED panel product in a way so that the on/off function(Physical Switch present at the top right corner) is controlled by arduino pro mini 3.5V version.
By the way, this LED panel is powered by 4xAA battery too.

- I also want to power the arduino pro mini (3.v) from same battery source.
- Please consider that I want to add a Bluetooth module to this arduino later to control from a phone camera app to use the LED panel as camera flash 
  (I have tested this step in another project already and no issues).

What is the best way to turn the this LED panel on/off considering my requirements above?

Comment: Have use used the Serial.read() and Serial.write()?  They are built in function for UART.  Whatever you want to transmit through Bluetooth,  you need to transfer the data to the module using UART at 9600 baud rate.

Comment: I’m asking help for circuit design on how should I hook up relay or transistor with the LED and arduino so that the led turn on/off can be done by arduino.No issue with coding, Thanks

Comment: You will get a better response if you ask "what is better to use for switching 3 volts 5.5 watts LED? " You may get a proper model number of MOSFET. I worked with 12 volts MOSFET only.

Comment: @Sadat Thank you so much.